# List sorting except specific element

Tags: python, list, sorting

I made nested list

```
information = [['name', 'age', 'sex', 'height', 'weight'], ['sam', '17', 'm', 155, 55], [...]] to make table.
```

and I want to sort data according to height. but when I use `.sort()` method, because of `information[0]`, this error message comes out

```
"TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'"
```

how can I sort data except first element?

[image]

[image]

As you can see first picture, i made table to see in excel file.
ans I want to sort elements according to G column. (this is the code of movie info)
but when I tried sorting using sort(), because the top element is "러닝타임+평점"(str type), sorting is not able.

Comment: Can you show what have you done so far?

Comment: @ncica ookay, i'll edit this post to see easy.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sorted` with the 4th element as key on a slice of `information` that doesn't hold the headers

```
information[1:] = sorted(information[1:], key=lambda x: x[3])
```

Answer (score 2):

if using of pandas library is acceptable then you can do this
create as dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(information)

# make the first row as column names
headers = df.iloc[0]
# create a updated dataframe with those new column names
updated_df = pd.DataFrame(df.values[1:], columns=headers)

# sort the values based on height
updated_df.sort_values('height', inplace=True)
```

Comment: What is the point of creating the first dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame(information)`, since you're going to ignore it and create a new one immediately after?

Comment: I did with the minimal effort as it was asked. Of course, we could take that first element from that 2d list and then remove that one from the original lists and create dataframe and then simply assign the first element from 2d list as a columns.